# C++ own character-encoding

Tags: c++, character-encoding, hex

Is it possible to create an own character-encoding/ charset table and type in C++?

For example create a character-encoding with only the follow characters:

```
+-----------+------+
| character | code |
+-----------+------+
|     0     | 0000 |
|     1     | 0001 |
|     2     | 0010 |
|     3     | 0011 |
|     4     | 0100 |
|     5     | 0101 |
|     6     | 0110 |
|     7     | 0111 |
|     8     | 1000 |
|     9     | 1001 |
|     A     | 1010 |
|     B     | 1011 |
|     C     | 1100 |
|     D     | 1101 |
|     E     | 1110 |
|     F     | 1111 |
+-----------+------+
```

Like the ASCII Codes 48-57 and 65-70 but 9+1 should be A and F+1 should be 10.

Comment: Of course you can, however you will not find any 4bit type, so you will have to pack two encoded characters in a single `uint8` to have any advantage over ASCII `char`.

Comment: You could define an array `char enc[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };`, and then when you have a character `c` you want to print, you print `enc[c]`  instead. Would that be what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
Maybe I should rephrase the question.

Whatever, in my case the best solution was to use a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/).