# How to make my own character encoding in C++?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I need to define a character set in C++. I have already checked the document [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268804/c-own-character-encoding), but what I am looking for is little more wide range. For example I have letters like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTcX2.png).

To type these characters, I will make a virtual keyboard. I am assuming that I have already give a code for each character. I have the font of this character set. Problem is, when I hit a key from virtual keyboard, it will write the key as, for example, 'q'. It will look like, in text field, one of the letters in the photo that I showed, but at the background, the actual letter is 'q'. When I copy that letter to somewhere else, it will write 'q' letter. [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWgny.png)

Although I have no intention to copy that letters somewhere else, I would like to give them a code and, when I write, it will be different than 'q'.

I wouldn't have a problem with representing that letter with 'q' if I didn't work with at least two ancient languages. (Ancient Greek, Ancient Turkish)

It will be like an ASCII encoding, but isolated from outside of the program.

I hope I described my problem well.

Comment: You need a list of all the characters so you can assign ordinals, and based on that a font for rendering them. If you have that, you can get started. Still, sure the neccessary characters aren't already in unicode? And really sure you don't want to use the private-use-area to describe them, to enable mixing them with other scripts?

Comment: There are unicode character representations for both ancient Greek and ancient Turkish. But since those languages are too old and nobody bothering them, I couldn't do the unicode way. I had a few attempts but they didn't worked.

Comment: Use Unicode. It already defines characters for most languages most people will ever need. If that's not enough, it has a private use area.

Comment: *Why* and *how* didn't that work? Maybe it's as simple as getting a better font? Or at least less work than building your own solution from scratch, which will not be integrated into anything else?

Comment: "since those languages are too old and nobody bothering them, I couldn't do the unicode way." This doesn't make any sense. What was your specific problem?

Comment: First, there are no fonts for ancient Turkish. Even in Unicode's website, I couldn't find them. I decided to create the font, I did, with appropriate code representations. But since the language itself reads-writes from right to left, I couldn't find a way to implement in C++. And I will not publish the program, I will use it on my own.

Comment: @Deduplicator thank you. But I don't understand that what you mean by character list? Font?

Comment: No, the mapping the font should be based on, between characters and ordinals.

Comment: "no fonts for ancient Turkish" This is not a reason to create your own *encoding*, and [are you really sure](http://www.fontspace.com/category/old%20turkic)? "the language itself reads-writes from right to left" It's not like there is any shortage of living kicking languages that read right to left. There are at least 300,000,000 people on this Earth that use such languages. Unicode works for those people, have no doubt about it.

Comment: "I am sure that those who use scripts like I search for don't use computers." OK suppose I don't use computers ;) but why insult hundreds of millions people along with me? Maybe you should read Arabic and Farsi support in Unicode, then wonder how many cell phones (which are Unicode-enabled computers) with RTL suport are shipped daily.

Comment: OK sorry but let me ask you this. Why are you judging me for the question I asked? :) I don't insult you nor anybody. I just have a problem and I want an answer, and I thank you for the font.

Comment: @BoraSemiz It's normally the output device which handles the direction of writing.  You may have to add some sort of parameters to your font to ensure that the output device knows the direction.  Or it may be using the UnicodeData.txt file; old Turkic has been added fairly recently,so unless the display device has a very up-to-date version of this file, it may not know that it is right to left.  Or maybe you can force it with the RLE and LRE characters.

Comment: @BoraSemiz "I am sure that those who use scripts like I search for don't use computers.": You mention ancient Greek and ancient Turkic.  About the only people who do use these alphabets today are scholars, and they almost certainly use computers.

Comment: @JamesKanze thank you. But I am not going to use Unicode method now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not judging anyone. I'm just telling that your needs are, with a very high probability, not unique. Someone has already developed what you are trying to do and integrated it into your OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's take a stab at an answer.

First, don't bother with narrow characters. That's just a pain to work with. Use `wchar_t`. Secondly, on relevant systems `wchar_t` maps to some form of Unicode, and Unicode has a Private Use Area (PUA). Assign PUA values to each of your characters. This takes care of the binary representation of your texts.

Secondly, you'll need an input method. This is OS-specific, and you haven't specified which OS. And we don't know what script you have, so we don't know whether keys to characters are a 1-to-1 mapping or more complex.

Finally, you'd need a way to display these scripts. This can be solved in two ways. Either you provide a font to the OS, and let the OS render your texts with that, or you take over rendering yourself. Neither is easy, and both are to a degree OS-specific (which we still don't know).

Comment: My operating system is Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.